# Set order of Recommended reading in the Developer Story section of Stack Overflow account

Tags: feature-request

It would be useful to be able to change the order of items of the list of Recommended reading in the Developer Story section of Stack Overflow account using drag and drop as well as using up/down/top/bottom buttons or contextual popup menu.